# Hiding And Showing multiple areas based on radiobuttonlist input selected

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I had a similar question to this before but I had to modify it because the user changed their mind. I am working on a script that if option 0 is selected it should show "remind" otherwise keep it hidden. If option 2 is selected it should unhide "cc" otherwise keep it hidden. My problem is that once the event is fired regardless of option 0 or 2 both areas open up. I was just wondering if i could get some help having them work separate.
 Here is the JS:

```
 $('#rbPType').change(function () {
 var op1 = $(this).attr('value', '0');
 var op2 = $(this).attr('value', '2');

 if (op1) {
    $('#remind').fadeIn();
 } else {
    $('#remind').fadeOut();
 }

 $(this).change(function () {
     $('#remind').toggle();
 });

 if (op2) {
     $('#cc').fadeIn();
 } else {
     $('#cc').fadeOut();
 }

 $(this).change(function () {
     $('#cc').toggle();
 });

 });
```

HTML

```
<div class="another">
<label for="rbPType">Select One</label>
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rbPType" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>
<div id="remind">
<label for="ddlReminderMonth">Remind Me</label>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlReminderMonth" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="false" />
</div>
<div id="cc">
<label for="ddlReminderMonth">Remind Me Two</label>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlReminderMonth" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="false" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have two dropdownlists with same `ddlReminderMonth`.

Your controls appear and disappear after click, because of toggle. Toggle makes your code really confusing.

```
<div class="another">
    <label for="rbPType">
        Select One</label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rbPType" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="3"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>
<div id="remind">
    <label for="ddlReminderMonth">
        Remind Me</label>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlReminderMonth1" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
        AutoPostBack="false" />
</div>
<div id="cc">
    <label for="ddlReminderMonth">
        Remind Me Two</label>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlReminderMonth2" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
        AutoPostBack="false" />
</div>


<script>
    $('#rbPType').change(function () {
        var value = $('#rbPType input:checked').val();

        if (value == '0') {
            $('#remind').fadeIn();
            $('#cc').fadeOut();
        }
        else if (value == '1') {
            // Show or hide
        }
        else { // value == '2'
            $('#remind').fadeOut();
            $('#cc').fadeIn();
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: sorry about the mess with the html. Again you are my savior!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are writing lot of unnecessary code here. jquery toggle takes boolean parameter which when true would show the selected field and when false would hide it.

```
    $('#rbPType').change(function () {
     var op1 = $(this).attr('value', '0');
     var op2 = $(this).attr('value', '2');
     $('#remind').toggle(op1);
     $('#cc').toggle(op2);
    });
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Well this one had items unhidden even when it shouldnt have been. I wasnt sure why

Comment: can you alert the values in op1 and op2 variables..I suspect you are not getting expected flag at these variables.